# open a server side directory in a web browser tab or file browser window?

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a shiny app which generates some files and save them in a directory in file server location. After generating the file, I want to work on the files interactively with other applications.

It should work something like this:

1. /srv/shiny-server/myapp/app.R running on http://localhost/myapp
2. Visit http://localhost/myapp and click a button "open /home/"
3. A File browser window is open for /home/ or a new tab on internet browser (i.e. Firefox, Chrome).

I've tried:

1. `actionButton` with `onclick="window.open('file:///home/<username>', '_blank')"` => failed due to security feature of web browser)
2. `system('firefox file://...')` failed with `Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`

A possible third option is to save the files to `/srv/shiny-server/myapp/www` and make links to that. But that means I have to copies of files on the server. What is the more elegant way to achieve this seemingly open a file browser window?

Please note that the server is accessed by remote desktop and the app is access locally in that remote desktop session. So, I want to avoid using "download button" if that is possible.

Comment: You can use `addResourcePath` to have shiny serve your file from its original location

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addResourcePath` to have shiny serve your file from its original location

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(htmlOutput("link"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  addResourcePath("res", "/my/folder/containing/my/file")
  output$link = renderUI(HTML('<A HREF="res/file_name">Download</A>'))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works partially: I can addResourcePath and create hyperlink to every single file. It doesn't work with directory level. For example: <A HREF="res/">Output Dir</A> doesn't work.